# NDIS filter driver' FilterReceiveNetBufferLists handler isn't called

Tags: c, windows, driver, function-calls, ndis

I am developing an NDIS filter driver, and I fount its `FilterReceiveNetBufferLists` is never called (the network is blocked) under certain condition (like open Wireshark or click the "Interface List" button of it). But When I start the capturing, the `FilterReceiveNetBufferLists` get to be normal (network restored), this is so strange.

I found that when I mannually return `NDIS_STATUS_FAILURE` for the `NdisFOidRequest` function in an OID originating place of WinPcap driver (BIOCQUERYOID & BIOCSETOID switch branch of NPF_IoControl), then driver won't block the network (Also the winpcap can't work).

**Is there something wrong with the `NdisFOidRequest` call?**

The DeviceIO routine in Packet.c that originates OID requests:

```
case BIOCQUERYOID:
case BIOCSETOID:

    TRACE_MESSAGE(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "BIOCSETOID - BIOCQUERYOID");

    //
    // gain ownership of the Ndis Handle
    //
    if (NPF_StartUsingBinding(Open) == FALSE)
    {
        //
        // MAC unbindind or unbound
        //
        SET_FAILURE_INVALID_REQUEST();
        break;
    }


    // Extract a request from the list of free ones
    RequestListEntry = ExInterlockedRemoveHeadList(&Open->RequestList, &Open->RequestSpinLock);
    if (RequestListEntry == NULL)
    {
        //
        // Release ownership of the Ndis Handle
        //
        NPF_StopUsingBinding(Open);

        SET_FAILURE_NOMEM();
        break;
    }

    pRequest = CONTAINING_RECORD(RequestListEntry, INTERNAL_REQUEST, ListElement);

    //
    //  See if it is an Ndis request
    //
    OidData = Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;

    if ((IrpSp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength == IrpSp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength) &&
        (IrpSp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength >= sizeof(PACKET_OID_DATA)) &&
        (IrpSp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength >= sizeof(PACKET_OID_DATA) - 1 + OidData->Length))
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE2(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "BIOCSETOID|BIOCQUERYOID Request: Oid=%08lx, Length=%08lx", OidData->Oid, OidData->Length);

        //
        //  The buffer is valid
        //
        NdisZeroMemory(&pRequest->Request, sizeof(NDIS_OID_REQUEST));
        pRequest->Request.Header.Type = NDIS_OBJECT_TYPE_OID_REQUEST;
        pRequest->Request.Header.Revision = NDIS_OID_REQUEST_REVISION_1;
        pRequest->Request.Header.Size = NDIS_SIZEOF_OID_REQUEST_REVISION_1;

        if (FunctionCode == BIOCSETOID)
        {
            pRequest->Request.RequestType = NdisRequestSetInformation;
            pRequest->Request.DATA.SET_INFORMATION.Oid = OidData->Oid;

            pRequest->Request.DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBuffer = OidData->Data;
            pRequest->Request.DATA.SET_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength = OidData->Length;
        }
        else
        {
            pRequest->Request.RequestType = NdisRequestQueryInformation;
            pRequest->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.Oid = OidData->Oid;

            pRequest->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.InformationBuffer = OidData->Data;
            pRequest->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength = OidData->Length;
        }

        NdisResetEvent(&pRequest->InternalRequestCompletedEvent);

        if (*((PVOID *) pRequest->Request.SourceReserved) != NULL)
        {
            *((PVOID *) pRequest->Request.SourceReserved) = NULL;
        }
        //
        //  submit the request
        //
        pRequest->Request.RequestId = (PVOID) NPF6X_REQUEST_ID;
        ASSERT(Open->AdapterHandle != NULL);
        Status = NdisFOidRequest(Open->AdapterHandle, &pRequest->Request);
        //Status = NDIS_STATUS_FAILURE;
    }
    else
    {
        //
        // Release ownership of the Ndis Handle
        //
        NPF_StopUsingBinding(Open);

        //
        //  buffer too small
        //
        SET_FAILURE_BUFFER_SMALL();
        break;
    }

    if (Status == NDIS_STATUS_PENDING)
    {
        NdisWaitEvent(&pRequest->InternalRequestCompletedEvent, 1000);
        Status = pRequest->RequestStatus;
    }

    //
    // Release ownership of the Ndis Handle
    //
    NPF_StopUsingBinding(Open);

    //
    // Complete the request
    //
    if (FunctionCode == BIOCSETOID)
    {
        OidData->Length = pRequest->Request.DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesRead;
        TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "BIOCSETOID completed, BytesRead = %u", OidData->Length);
    }
    else
    {
        if (FunctionCode == BIOCQUERYOID)
        {
            OidData->Length = pRequest->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesWritten;

            if (Status == NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                //
                // check for the stupid bug of the Nortel driver ipsecw2k.sys v. 4.10.0.0 that doesn't set the BytesWritten correctly
                // The driver is the one shipped with Nortel client Contivity VPN Client V04_65.18, and the MD5 for the buggy (unsigned) driver
                // is 3c2ff8886976214959db7d7ffaefe724 *ipsecw2k.sys (there are multiple copies of this binary with the same exact version info!)
                // 
                // The (certified) driver shipped with Nortel client Contivity VPN Client V04_65.320 doesn't seem affected by the bug.
                //
                if (pRequest->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesWritten > pRequest->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength)
                {
                    TRACE_MESSAGE2(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Bogus return from NdisRequest (query): Bytes Written (%u) > InfoBufferLength (%u)!!", pRequest->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesWritten, pRequest->Request.DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.InformationBufferLength);

                    Status = NDIS_STATUS_INVALID_DATA;
                }
            }

            TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "BIOCQUERYOID completed, BytesWritten = %u", OidData->Length);
        }
    }


    ExInterlockedInsertTailList(&Open->RequestList, &pRequest->ListElement, &Open->RequestSpinLock);

    if (Status == NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        SET_RESULT_SUCCESS(sizeof(PACKET_OID_DATA) - 1 + OidData->Length);
    }
    else
    {
        SET_FAILURE_INVALID_REQUEST();
    }

    break;
```

**Three Filter OID routines:**

```
_Use_decl_annotations_
NDIS_STATUS
NPF_OidRequest(
    NDIS_HANDLE         FilterModuleContext,
    PNDIS_OID_REQUEST   Request
    )
{
    POPEN_INSTANCE          Open = (POPEN_INSTANCE) FilterModuleContext;
    NDIS_STATUS             Status;
    PNDIS_OID_REQUEST       ClonedRequest=NULL;
    BOOLEAN                 bSubmitted = FALSE;
    PFILTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT Context;
    BOOLEAN                 bFalse = FALSE;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    do
    {
        Status = NdisAllocateCloneOidRequest(Open->AdapterHandle,
                                            Request,
                                            NPF6X_ALLOC_TAG,
                                            &ClonedRequest);
        if (Status != NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            TRACE_MESSAGE(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "FilerOidRequest: Cannot Clone Request\n");
            break;
        }

        Context = (PFILTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT)(&ClonedRequest->SourceReserved[0]);
        *Context = Request;

        bSubmitted = TRUE;

        //
        // Use same request ID
        //
        ClonedRequest->RequestId = Request->RequestId;

        Open->PendingOidRequest = ClonedRequest;

        Status = NdisFOidRequest(Open->AdapterHandle, ClonedRequest);

        if (Status != NDIS_STATUS_PENDING)
        {
            NPF_OidRequestComplete(Open, ClonedRequest, Status);
            Status = NDIS_STATUS_PENDING;
        }


    }while (bFalse);

    if (bSubmitted == FALSE)
    {
        switch(Request->RequestType)
        {
            case NdisRequestMethod:
                Request->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesRead = 0;
                Request->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded = 0;
                Request->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesWritten = 0;
                break;

            case NdisRequestSetInformation:
                Request->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesRead = 0;
                Request->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded = 0;
                break;

            case NdisRequestQueryInformation:
            case NdisRequestQueryStatistics:
            default:
                Request->DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesWritten = 0;
                Request->DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded = 0;
                break;
        }

    }

    TRACE_EXIT();
    return Status;

}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

_Use_decl_annotations_
VOID
NPF_CancelOidRequest(
    NDIS_HANDLE             FilterModuleContext,
    PVOID                   RequestId
    )
{
    POPEN_INSTANCE                      Open = (POPEN_INSTANCE) FilterModuleContext;
    PNDIS_OID_REQUEST                   Request = NULL;
    PFILTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT             Context;
    PNDIS_OID_REQUEST                   OriginalRequest = NULL;
    BOOLEAN                             bFalse = FALSE;

    FILTER_ACQUIRE_LOCK(&Open->OIDLock, bFalse);

    Request = Open->PendingOidRequest;

    if (Request != NULL)
    {
        Context = (PFILTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT)(&Request->SourceReserved[0]);

        OriginalRequest = (*Context);
    }

    if ((OriginalRequest != NULL) && (OriginalRequest->RequestId == RequestId))
    {
        FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&Open->OIDLock, bFalse);

        NdisFCancelOidRequest(Open->AdapterHandle, RequestId);
    }
    else
    {
        FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&Open->OIDLock, bFalse);
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

_Use_decl_annotations_
VOID
NPF_OidRequestComplete(
    NDIS_HANDLE         FilterModuleContext,
    PNDIS_OID_REQUEST   Request,
    NDIS_STATUS         Status
    )
{
    POPEN_INSTANCE                      Open = (POPEN_INSTANCE) FilterModuleContext;
    PNDIS_OID_REQUEST                   OriginalRequest;
    PFILTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT             Context;
    BOOLEAN                             bFalse = FALSE;

    TRACE_ENTER();

    Context = (PFILTER_REQUEST_CONTEXT)(&Request->SourceReserved[0]);
    OriginalRequest = (*Context);

    //
    // This is an internal request
    //
    if (OriginalRequest == NULL)
    {
        TRACE_MESSAGE1(PACKET_DEBUG_LOUD, "Status= %p", Status);
        NPF_InternalRequestComplete(Open, Request, Status);
        TRACE_EXIT();
        return;
    }


    FILTER_ACQUIRE_LOCK(&Open->OIDLock, bFalse);

    ASSERT(Open->PendingOidRequest == Request);
    Open->PendingOidRequest = NULL;

    FILTER_RELEASE_LOCK(&Open->OIDLock, bFalse);


    //
    // Copy the information from the returned request to the original request
    //
    switch(Request->RequestType)
    {
        case NdisRequestMethod:
            OriginalRequest->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.OutputBufferLength =  Request->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.OutputBufferLength;
            OriginalRequest->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesRead = Request->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesRead;
            OriginalRequest->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded = Request->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded;
            OriginalRequest->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesWritten = Request->DATA.METHOD_INFORMATION.BytesWritten;
            break;

        case NdisRequestSetInformation:
            OriginalRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesRead = Request->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesRead;
            OriginalRequest->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded = Request->DATA.SET_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded;
            break;

        case NdisRequestQueryInformation:
        case NdisRequestQueryStatistics:
        default:
            OriginalRequest->DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesWritten = Request->DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesWritten;
            OriginalRequest->DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded = Request->DATA.QUERY_INFORMATION.BytesNeeded;
            break;
    }


    (*Context) = NULL;

    NdisFreeCloneOidRequest(Open->AdapterHandle, Request);

    NdisFOidRequestComplete(Open->AdapterHandle, OriginalRequest, Status);

    TRACE_EXIT();
}
```

Comment: I cannot find a bug in that code.  My best guess is that one of the OIDs that Wireshark sends is breaking the network.  Most likely suspect is OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER.  When you force a failure, that probably stops Wireshark from sending the next OID.  Try adding a delay to the OID code, and check if packets are being received after each OID.  Figure out which OID is the one that breaks the NIC.

Comment: Another diagnostic to try - return NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS for every OID, but if the OID code is OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER, then don't actually send the OID down.  See if that gets the receive path to work.

Comment: You're so magic! I followed your advice, modified the status to NDIS_STATUS_SUCCESS for every OID no matter what NdisFOidRequest returned, bypassed the NdisFOidRequest invoke when OID code was OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER. Then what you guess, the Wireshark worked! But at the same time I still didn't get that why did it like this? what's wrong with OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER? Thx

Comment: I guessed that OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER is the problem because NDIS handles it differently for protocols vs filters.  Protocols are all peers of each other, but filters are layered on top of each other.  So when a protocol sends OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER, NDIS will merge that packet filter with the packet filter of all other protocols.  However, when a filter sets the packet filter, that just overwrites the packet filter on the miniport, potentially losing the packet filter that other protocols (like TCPIP) had asked for.

Comment: But the above modifying way is just for the test, right? I still need to get the actual return value for every OID except OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER, only bypassed the NdisFOidRequest invoke when OID code was OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER, is this the right way for final release of my driver? Also the OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER seems to be related with the "promiscuous mode" switch in Wireshark. If we disable OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER requests, does it mean that the "promiscuous mode" switch will always be "ON"? Is there a way to solve with this? Thx.

Comment: Yes, that was just to try and narrow down the problem.  Production code should pass along the true NDIS_STATUS code from the lower layer.  The best way to handle this is to have your filter keep track of the current packet filter and OR in the promiscuous flag when it needs to enable promiscuous mode.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "keep track of the current packet filter and OR in the promiscuous flag when it needs to enable promiscuous mode"? packet filter is not the filter driver or the filter module, right? Also I didn't get what is a "OR"? Thx

Comment: The packet filter is a bitmask of flags.  When NDIS calls your filter's FilterOidRequest, you can peek at the OIDs that are flowing down through the filter.  If you see an OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER request go down, stash away the packet filter in that OID -- it's the value from above your filter.  Now when you want to modify the packet filter, do a bitwise-OR operation to add your new flags to the value from above, and send that OID down.  Finally, to clear your packet filter, set the previous value that you saw from the upper layer.  Here's some pseudo-code: http://pastebin.com/ZMzuBpF8

Comment: I did as the example but no luck. But I found the problem is indeed in the packet filter. When Wireshark lists the adapters, my driver calls NdisFOidRequest with the NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL data under OID: OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER, then I can't receive indication any more. When Wireshark starts capturing, my driver calls NdisFOidRequest with the NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS data under OID: OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER, then I can receive again. The HigherPacketFilter is always NULL, because no other applications set the packet filter.

Comment: I just didn't understand why NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL would break the receive path? NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL and NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS are two best flags for a packet capture software like WinPcap, isn't it? NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL for normal caputre and NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS for promiscuous capture?

Comment: Oh, you don't need NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL anymore.  Your filter always gets all local traffic, since it's sitting lower in the network stack.  That flag is only used for loopback traffic, which you don't need anymore.

Comment: you mean NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL is only for protocol driver, right? Also I should use the NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS flag for promiscuous capture. It's not hard to think. But if I cannot use NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL flag, what flag should I use for non-promiscuous capture in Wireshark? You know WinPcap uses packet.dll as the higher level for the driver. Maybe I should change the PacketSetHwFilter function in packet.dll to use another flag instead of NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL? Thx

Comment: Yeah, NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL isn't useful for LWFs.  You'll get "non-promiscuous" capture automatically by default; no need to send any OID.  Only when you enable promiscuous mode should you send down a new OID with the promiscuous flag added in.

Comment: But if Wireshark switches from the "promiscuous" mode to the "non-promiscuous" mode, the npf driver has to send a new flag to substitute the old NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS flag, right? Maybe NULL is ok? or NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_DIRECTED | NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_MULTICAST | NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_BROADCAST? Which one is the default? thx

Comment: Thx, Jeffery, you solved this problem so well! Would you mind if I post your mail as the answer for this question? Or you can answer it by yourself, then I will close it :)

Comment: You are certainly welcome to quote my email here if you think you can preserve the formatting and pictures :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

---

Below is the mail I received from Jeffrey, I think it is the best answer for this question:)

---

The packet filter works differently for LWFs versus Protocols.  Let me give you some background.  You’ll already know some of this, I’m sure, but it’s always helpful to review the basics, so we can be sure that we’re both on the same page.  The NDIS datapath is organized like a tree:

[image]

Packet filtering happens at two places in this stack:

(a)   once in the miniport hardware, and

(b)  at the top of the stack, just below the protocols.

NDIS will track each protocols’ packet filter separately, for efficiency.  If one protocol asks to see ALL packets (promiscuous mode), then not all protocols have to sort through all that traffic.  So really, there are (**P**+1) different packet filters in the system, where **P** is the number of protocols:

[image]

Now if there are all these different packet filters, how does an OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER actually work?  What NDIS does is NDIS tracks each protocols’ packet filter, but also merges the filter at the top of the miniport stack. So suppose protocol0 requests a packet filter of A+B, and protocol1 requests a packet filter of C, and protocol2 requests a packet filter of B+D:

[image]

Then at the top of the stack, NDIS merges the packet filters to A+B+C+D.  This is what gets sent down the filter stack, and eventually to the miniport.

Because of this merging process, no matter what protocol2 sets as its packet filter, protocol2 cannot affect the other protocols.  So protocols don’t have to worry about “sharing” the packet filter.  However, the same is not true for a LWF.  If LWF1 decides to set a new packet filter, it does not get merged:

[image]

In the above picture, LWF1 decided to change the packet filter to C+E.  This overwrote the protocols’ packet filter of A+B+C+D, meaning that flags A, B, and D will never make it to the hardware.  If the protocols were relying on flags A, B, or D, then the protocols’ functionality will be broken.

This is by design – LWFs have great power, and they can do anything to the stack.  They are designed to have the power to veto the packet filters of all other protocols.  But in your case, you don’t want to mess with other protocols; you want your filter to have minimal effects on the rest of the system.

So what you want to do is to always keep track of what the packet filter is, and never remove flags from the current packet filter.  That means that you should query the packet filter when your filter attaches, and update your cached value whenever you see an OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER come down from above.

If your usermode app needs more flags than what the current packet filter has, you can issue the OID and add additional flags. This means that the hardware’s packet filter will have more flags.  But no protocol’s packet filter will change, so the protocols will still see the same stuff.

[image]

In the above example, the filter LWF1 is playing nice.  Even though LWF1 only cares about flag E, LWF1 has still passed down all flags A, B, C, and D too, since LWF1 knows that the protocols above it want those flags to be set.

The code to manage this isn’t too bad, once you get the idea of what needs to be done to manage the packet filter:

1. Always track the latest packet filter from protocols above.
2. Never let the NIC see a packet filter that has fewer flags than the protocols’ packet filter.
3. Add in your own flags as needed.

Ok, hopefully that gives you a good idea of what the packet filter is and how to manage it.  The next question is how to map “promiscuous mode” and “non-promiscuous mode” into actual flags?  Let’s define these two modes carefully:

**Non-promiscuous mode**: The capture tool only sees the receive traffic that the operating system would normally have received.  If the hardware filters out traffic, then we don’t want to see that traffic. The user wants to diagnose the local operating system in its normal state.

**Promiscuous mode**: Give the capture tool as many receive packets as possible – ideally every bit that is transferred on the wire.  It doesn’t matter whether the packet was destined for the local host or not.  The user wants to diagnose the network, and so wants to see everything happening on the network.

I think when you look at it that way, the consequences for the packet filter flags are fairly straightforward.  For non-promiscuous mode, do not change the packet filter.  Just let the hardware packet filter be whatever the operating system wants it to be.  Then for promiscuous mode, add in the NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS flag, and the NIC hardware will give you everything it possibly can.

So if it’s that simple for a LWF, why did the old protocol-based NPF driver need so many more flags?  The old protocol-based driver had a couple problems:

1. It can’t get “non-promiscuous mode” perfectly correct
2. It can’t easily capture the send-packets of other protocols

The first problem with NPF-protocol is that it can’t easily implement our definition of “non-promiscuous mode” correctly.  If NPF-the-protocol wants to see receive traffic just as the OS sees it, then what packet filter should it use?  If it sets a packet filter of zero, then NPF won’t see any traffic.  So NPF can set a packet filter of Directed|Broadcast|Multicast.  But that’s only an assumption of what TCPIP and other protocols are setting.  If TCPIP decided to set a Promiscuous flag (certain socket flags cause this to happen), then NPF would actually be seeing fewer packets than what TCPIP would see, which is wrong.  But if NPF sets the Promiscuous flag, then it will see more traffic than TCPIP would see, which is also wrong.  So it’s tough for a capturing protocol to decide which flags to set so that it sees exactly the same packets that the rest of the OS sees.  LWFs don’t have that problem, since LWFs get to see the combined OID after all protocols’ filters are merged.

The second problem with NPF-protocol is that it needed loopback mode to capture sent-packets.  LWFs don’t need loopback -- in fact, it would be actively harmful.  Let’s use the same diagram to see why.  Here’s NPF capturing the receive path in promiscuous mode:

[image]

Now let’s see what happens when a unicast packet is received:

[image]

Since the packet matches the hardware’s filter, the packet comes up the stack.  Then when the packet gets to the protocol layer, NDIS gives the packet to both protocols, tcpip and npf, since both protocols’ packet filters match the packet. So that works well enough.

But now the send path is tricky:

[image]

tcpip sent a packet, but npf never got a chance to see it!  To solve this problem, NDIS added the notion of a “loopback” packet filter flag.  This flag is a little bit special, since it doesn’t go to the hardware.  Instead, the loopback packet filter tells NDIS to bounce all send-traffic back up the receive path, so that diagnostics tools like npf can see the packets.  It looks like this:

[image]

Now the loopback path is really only used for diagnostics tools, so we haven’t spent much time optimizing it.  And, since it means that all send packets travel across the stack twice (once for the normal send path, and again in the receive path), it has at least double the CPU cost.  This is why I said that an NDIS LWF would be able to be capture at a higher throughput than a protocol, since LWFs don’t need the loopback path.

Why not?  Why don’t LWFs need loopback?  Well if you go back and look at the last few diagrams, you’ll see that all of our LWFs saw all the traffic – both send and receive – without any loopback.  So the LWF meets the requirements of seeing all traffic, without needing to bother with loopback.  That’s why a LWF should normally never set any loopback flags.

Ok, that email got longer than I wanted, but I hope that clears up some of the questions around the packet filter, the loopback path, and how LWFs are different from protocols.  Please let me know if anything wasn’t clear, or if the diagrams didn’t come through.